# use JavaScript map reduce to remove items from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, reduce

I have a JavaScript example with map reduce to remove items from an array, after transforming them. Is there a simpler method to achieve this as it seems a bit complicated

I [put it in a JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jezza/2hnH7/) and here is the map reduce part:

```
var after = before.map(function (item) {
    if (item.keep) {
        return {
            z: item.a
        };
    } else {
        return undefined;
    }
}).reduce(function (prev, item) {
    if (item) {
        if ($.isArray(prev)) {
            prev.push(item);
            return prev;
        } else if (prev) {
            return [prev, item];
        } else {
            return [item];
        }
    } else {
        if ($.isArray(prev)) {
            return prev;
        } else if (prev) {
            return [prev];
        } else {
            return prev;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe try the splice method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

```
var after = before.filter(function (item) {
   return item.keep;
});
```

Then you can still `.map` it if you want/need to.

Comment: `var after = before.filter(function (item) {
        return item.keep;
    }).map(function (item) {
        return {
            z: item.a
        };
    })` That was exactly it. Thanks